# Maximal sidelength of a square containing a point and intersecting no other square

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization, dynamic-programming

Given a list of squares L, each embedded (non-overlapping) in an n x n grid, I would like to find the sidelength of the largest square (not in L) which contains an given position (i,j) and does not intersect any square in L.

Each square is represented by the position of its top-left corner and its sidelength, so it is very efficient to check whether two squares intersect.

How might I optimally find the value I describe above?

The algorithm I currently have essentially brute-force checks through every possible square containing (i,j) and keeps track of the maximal sidelength among those which intersect no square in L. I imagine this is nowhere close to optimal, although I've had trouble coming up with anything significantly faster.

Comment: just to be sure, (i,j) is not in a existing square ? Else that square would be the answer, right ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add a new square which covers the position (i,j). If (i,j) is already inside a square I would just return 0.